# Sound Mananger 2 setup problems

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a lot of trouble configuring Sound Manager 2. All I want to do is add the mp3-player-button to my mp3 links, however when clicked it redirects the user to the source's webpage with just an audio player and plays the song.  I can't seem how to configure Sound Manager 2 to just play the links within my site.

In my header is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/soundmanager/demo/mp3-player-button/css/mp3-player-button.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/soundmanager/script/soundmanager2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/soundmanager/demo/mp3-player-button/script/mp3-player-button.js"></script>
```

Where i output the code is in my body

```
<p><a href="linktomp3" class="sm2_button"</p>
```

That is all I did, but it does not seem to work at all :(

Comment: You have not setup `SM2'please see the Example http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/template/

Comment: Okay i just looked at the link, where should i place that code? In my header under the scripts or in the body?

Comment: in Head under the script

Comment: Okay and one more thing, where it says  url: '/path/to/swf-files/', i should put /soundmanager/swf/soundmanager2.swf? And where it says url: '/path/to/an.mp3' i should be putting the link to the specific mp3 file?

Comment: YOu are done with it?

Comment: No I'm still having alot of trouble getting it to work, it keeps redirecting to a different page and 3 buttons appear when only 1 should :( anyway you can help me via chat on skype or something? Id greatly appreciate it

Comment: Please Share your code i definately try to find solution

Comment: i feel a little uncomfortable posting my code, anyway to chat?